# Http get insinde another http get.map Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, http, typescript, asynchronous

What I think is wrong with this code is that before my inner http get is done, the parent get is already finished. I'm pasting the code and below is the description of what's wrong.

```
public getView$(nodeId : string): Observable<NavigatorSchema> {

    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('id', nodeId || '');
    let extensions: any = [];

    return this.http.get(resources.serviceViewEndpointURI, {search: params})
     .map((res: Response): NavigatorSchema => {
            console.log(this);

         this.legacyExtService.getAllExtensions().then( (data:any) => {
             extensions = data.data;
         });

         function contains(a: any, b: any) {
             let i = a.length;
             while (i--) {
                 if (a[i] === b) {
                     return true;
                 }
             }
             return false;
         }

        if (!!res.text()) {
            let response = res.json();

            response.children.forEach((obj: any) => {
                if (obj.children) {
                    obj.children.forEach((ext: any) => {
                        if (contains(extensions, ext.uid)) {
                            ext.class1 = 'edited-item';
                            ext.class2 = 'removed';
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

           return response;
        }

        throw(new Error("bad nodeId, malformed response"));
     });
```

}

So what is happening with this code, which by the way is in a service, is that every time the get requests are executed, the extensions array is what the this.legacyExtService.getAllExtensions() previously returned. So say i invoke the method getView and the result set from getAllExtensions should be:

"one", "two", "three"

then I call getView again, but this time the result set is {"one", "two", "three", "four"}. But when I make the check in the for loops - the content is the one I previouslt had gotten - {"one", "two", "three"}. I'm guessing this is because the "parent" get is executed before the getAllExtensions is and then the next time I get the value from the previous execution? If that's the case any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

----- edit

Is it even acceptable to call another get request from the `http.get.map(){//here}` ? Because I see that this is causing some problems. If not how can I work around that, having that my http.get is directly returned.

----edit 2-----
NavigatorSchema is the following class:

```
export interface NavigatorSchema {
   id: string;
   navigationTargetId: string;
   title: string;
   icon: string | null;
   class1?: string | null;
   class2?: string | null;
}
```

This is the legacyExtService.getAllExtensions method:

```
function getAllRemvedExtensions() {
    return $http.get('getAllRemovedExtensions');
}
```

Comment: (res: Response): NavigatorSchema what is that? And where is the nested HTTP get?

Comment: I edited my question with the NavigatorSchema class. And the nested http get comes from  this.legacyExtService.getAllExtensions(). The function getAllExtensions returns a get request like so: return $http.get('getAllExtensions');

Comment: Please update your question with the code from this.legacyExtService.getAllExtensions() (or at least its definition). Is the nested contains method being used in your code? if not, remove it

Comment: I updated it. Thanks for the replies and yes, contains is being used in the for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Any use of the variable `extensions` should be included in the promise of your second get:

```
this.legacyExtService.getAllExtensions().then( (data:any) => {
       extensions = data.data;
       (all other logic involving extensions)
});
```

This will prevent the call to `getAllExtensions()` being made then the code carrying on and using the old version of `extensions` before the promise has been fulfilled and hence the value of `extensions` has been updated.

Comment: I mean what I posted in the code snippet. The call to getAllExtensions is an async call it returns a Promise. Calling .then() on the promise executes the code only once the promise has been fulfilled (i.e. when the call is finished).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make API calls one by one in sequence instead of `map` operator try to use `switchMap`. The code should look something like this:

```
// your first API call
return this.http.get()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(firstData => { // firstData is the response you received from your first call

      // your second API call, make sure you 'return' it here so you can subscribe later
      return this.http.get()
    }),
  )
  .map(secondData => { // secondData is the response you received from your second call
    /* do your stuff here */
  });
```

Also, you might find helpful this [switchMap doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) or [this article](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/switchmap-in-details-b98d34145311).

From what I see now you're having a mixture of Observables and Promises which is not very good. It's recommended not to convert Observables to Promises.

--

In case you need to do multiple calls at the same time have a look at [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
public getView$(nodeId: string): Observable<NavigatorSchema> {

    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('id', nodeId || '');
    let extensions: any = [];

    return this.http.get(resources.serviceViewEndpointURI, { search: params })
        .map((res: Response): NavigatorSchema => {
            console.log(this);

            this.legacyExtService.getAllExtensions()
                .then((data: any) => {
                    extensions = data.data;
                })
                .then(() => {
                    function contains(a: any, b: any) {
                        let i = a.length;
                        while (i--) {
                            if (a[i] === b) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (!!res.text()) {
                        let response: any = res.json();
                        response.children.forEach((obj: any) => {
                            if (obj.children) {
                                obj.children.forEach((ext: any) => {
                                    if (contains(extensions, ext.uid)) {
                                        ext.class1 = 'edited-item';
                                        ext.class2 = 'removed';
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        return response;
                    }
                })
            throw (new Error("bad nodeId, malformed response"));
        });
}
```